# Can't compile Debian RefPolicy for SELinux

Tags: selinux, libselinux

I am using Debian 6 with SELinux enabled.

Now, I just want to change default policy and make my-policy as a active policy. For that I have downloaded debian's refpolicy and tried to compile it.

It seems `rolemap` file is not found. But `rolemap` is defined in `Makefile.src`.

Also, parsing `/tmp/example.tmp` file failed at `'introduce()' line:28`.

Find output of make at below:

```
debian:/opt/policy-src/debian# make -f Makefile.src all Compiling default example module echo "ifdef(\`""example""_per_role_template',\`" > tmp/example.mod.role m4
-D distro_debian -D direct_sysadm_daemon -D hide_broken_symptoms -D mls_num_sens=16 -D mls_num_cats=1024 -D mcs_num_cats=1024 -D mandatory_mcs rolemap | gawk '/^[[:blank:]]*[A-Za-z]/{ print "gen_require(type " $3 "; role " $1 ";)\nexample_per_role_template(" $2 "," $3 "," $1 ")" }' >> tmp/example.mod.role echo "')" >> tmp/example.mod.role echo "ifdef(\`""example""_per_userdomain_template',\`" >> tmp/example.mod.role echo "errprint(\`Warning: per_userdomain_templates have been renamed to per_role_templates (""example""_per_userdomain_template)'__endline__)" >> tmp/example.mod.role m4 -D distro_debian -D direct_sysadm_daemon -D hide_broken_symptoms -D mls_num_sens=16 -D mls_num_cats=1024 -D mcs_num_cats=1024 -D mandatory_mcs rolemap | gawk '/^[[:blank:]]*[A-Za-z]/{ print "gen_require(type " $3 "; role " $1 ";)\nexample_per_userdomain_template(" $2 "," $3 "," $1 ")" }' >> tmp/example.mod.role echo "')" >> tmp/example.mod.role m4 -D distro_debian -D direct_sysadm_daemon -D hide_broken_symptoms -D mls_num_sens=16 -D mls_num_cats=1024 -D mcs_num_cats=1024 -D mandatory_mcs -s tmp/all_interfaces.conf example.te tmp/example.mod.role > tmp/example.tmp /usr/bin/checkmodule -m tmp/example.tmp -o tmp/example.mod /usr/bin/checkmodule:  loading policy configuration from tmp/example.tmp tmp/all_interfaces.conf":28:ERROR 'Building a policy module, but no module specification found. ' at token 'interface' on line 28: interface(myapp_domtrans,
# /usr/bin/checkmodule:  error(s) encountered while parsing configuration make: *** [tmp/example.mod] Error 1
```

How could I compile this policy?

Answer (score 0):

To add your `my-policy` into the debian's refpolicy you have to work with the refpolicy (original sources) and the debian package (contains the example files).

See [how to work with debian sources](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/doc/source-unpack.txt). Instead of `make` you should use the Debian build tools.

Step by step:

- Source Package files for Debian 6 [selinux-policy-default](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/selinux-policy-default)
- run `dpkg-source -x refpolicy_0.2.20100524-7+squeeze1.dsc`
- goto "refpolicy-0.2.20100524" directory and make your changes
- build new debian package `dpkg-buildpackage`
- install new package `dpkg -i ../selinux-policy-default_0.2.20100524-7+squeeze1_all.deb`